# Sporadic issues with Stripe javascript in Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I have deployed a custom Stripe payment form in our app, and 97% of the time it works just fine. Occasionally, I see Stripe report an error on an attempted payment.

```
POST /v1/customers
error:
    type: "invalid_request_error"
    message: "You passed an empty string for 'card'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'card' cannot be unset. You should remove 'card' from your request or supply a non-empty value"
    param: "card"
```

This is raised when creating a customer with the Stripe token that should've been generated from the javascript:

```
    sale = current_user.sales.create(
        plan_id:   plan.id,
        amount:     plan.price_in_cents,
        stripe_token: params[:stripeToken]
    )
```

After much troubleshooting I've confirmed that this is happening because Stripe is not getting called in the first place to create the token. In other words, this is not an issue of passing params, where the token is generated but simply not passed to the controller. For some reason, something in the javascript is not running, so the form simply submits without it calling Stripe.

Again remember that 97% of the time this issue does not occur. When it does occur it happens to the same user over and over again. I have not found any pattern with browsers (it has happened on Chrome, IE, Firefox). Also, eventually users facing this problem have been able to successfully pay using the same browser and without any settings adjustments. This makes me think there's something potentially with my server environment and not the client.

Here is my full javascript:

subscription.js

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#paid_subscription');

  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $('#stripe_card_token').val(token);
    //$form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

jQuery(function($) {
  $('#card_number').payment('formatCardNumber')

  $('#paid_subscription').submit(function(event) {

    // var expiration = $("#card-expiry").payment("cardExpiryVal")
    // $('#card-exp-month').val(expiration.month);
    // $('#card-exp-year').val(expiration.year);

    var $form = $(this);

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

    // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
    return false;
  });
});
```

And here is the controller code, just in case:

charges#create

```
  def create

    token = params[:stripeToken]
    bundle = Bundle.find_by_id(params[:bundle_id])

    if bundle
      process_bundle_sale(bundle, token)
    else 
      plan = Plan.find(params[:plan_id])

      begin
        sale = current_user.sales.create(
            plan_id:   plan.id,
            amount:     plan.price_in_cents,
            stripe_token: params[:stripeToken]
        )
        sale.process!
        if sale.finished?
          if current_user.subscribe_with_referer({plan_id: plan.id}, session[:http_referer]) 
            TrackSubscriptions.track_paid_subscription(cookies, plan, sale)
            flash[:success] = "Success! You now have full access to \"#{plan.title}\""
            redirect_to plan_path(plan)
          else
            flash[:alert] = "Oops something went wrong. Please contact support and we'll get to the bottom of it."
            redirect_to plan_path(plan)
          end
        else
          flash[:alert] = sale.error
          redirect_to new_plan_subscription_path(plan.slug)
          #redirect_to plan_path(plan)
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

Finally here's the form code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @charge = Sale.new, :url => charges_path, :method => :post, html: { id: :paid_subscription } do |f| %>


<fieldset class = "inputWrapper">

            <h2 class="sub-header">Payment</h2>
          <span class="payment-errors"></span>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :plan_id, @plan.id %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag :stripeToken, nil,id: :stripe_card_token %>
          <div class="payment-fields">
                  <div class="field card-number-field">
                    <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                      <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, placeholder: "4444 1234 1234 1234",:data => {:stripe => 'number' } %>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field security-code-field">
                    <label class="control-label">Security Code</label>
                      <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, placeholder: "123", :data => {:stripe => 'cvc' } %>
                  </div>

                 <div class="field expiry-field">
                  <label class="control-label">Exp (MM/YYYY)</label>
                  <div class="month-field">
                    <%= text_field_tag :exp_month, nil, name: nil, placeholder: "10", id: "card-exp-month", maxlength: 2, data: { stripe: "exp-month" } %>
                    <span class="slash"> / </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="year-field">
                  <%= text_field_tag :exp_year, nil, name: nil, placeholder: "2016", id: "card-exp-year", maxlength: 4, data: { stripe: "exp-year" } %>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>

        <%= render 'end_form', :plan => @plan %>
        <div class="submit-button">
            <%= f.submit 'Register for Course', :class => "button greenButton", :error => false %>
        </div>
</fieldset>
        <% end %>
```

Comment: I'll wager the issue here is that the affected clients don't have working JavaScript. Since your form has a defined endpoint, JS-less clients will submit with the plan ID and no Stripe token. Having an empty form action and overriding it via your handler is/was recommended for this reason.

Comment: @colinm that was my first guess too, but I have since added a No-JS redirect, and yet still continue to see this issue. (see here: https://gist.github.com/pejmanjohn/d4cb9ec8998d99f06f8e)

Comment: Hmm. `stripe.js` is loaded before `subscription.js`, right? (It shouldn't work for anyone if not, but I'm just spitballing.) If you check your httpd logs, are the affected clients pulling down `subscription.js`?

Comment: If they're grabbing the JS, you might toss this on a NewRelic trial with RUM enabled; that would (or at least *should*) get any JS or DOM errors reported back to you.

Comment: @colinm Did some hygiene fixes to exactly match this tutorial as much as possible (https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/forms). Noticed that my Stripe.setPublishableKey was happening after subscription.js loaded. Not sure that matters, but fixed it anyways. Maybe more critical, I realized I was missing my body & html closing tags. Perhaps this will actually break things sporadically? Have never done tracking like you've mentioned but will check it out.

Comment: @colinm Ok I think I have something here. Got a user experiencing this issue to send me screenshots of her console in IE and Chrome. Check these out: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/443447/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-21%20at%206.28.21%20PM.png  and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/443447/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-21%20at%206.25.34%20PM.png Could it be the Cross-Origin thing?

Comment: None of these fixes seem to have made a difference. I have updated NewRelic to track JS errors. Will report back with what I find.

Comment: The issue appears to be resolved now. I cannot pinpoint exactly what did it, but I ended up removing a lot of unnecessary JS I had sitting around in my project. I noticed with NewRelic that this old JS was causing a lot of errors. I never saw an error directly on Stripe code, but in any case this seems to have fixed the problem.